# Magento 2 pub js file not change

Tags: magento2, js-css

Magento 2 changed `js` file.

After change `js` file run following command.

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy zh_Hans_CN`

In pub folder file has been change.

When I am trying to access `.js` file using url it does not show my changes.

Same things working in `localhost`. but not in live store `zh_Hans_CN`.

Comment: clear magento cache and browser cache or try with incognito mode

Comment: Try to access js using the ctfl +f5 , try to access js in private window

Comment: i tried whole these things, but not working

Answer (score 0):

Just run below CLI command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy zh_Hans_CN en_US
php bin/magento setup:cache:clean
```

Comment: files changed but frontend does not reflacted.

Comment: Check it in private window.

Answer (score 0):

Enable/allow symlinks through the Stores => Configuration => Advanced => Developer => Template Settings.

Delete pub static files,

And run

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento setup:cache:clean`